# How to migrate Flask-Sqlalchemy Models from another folder and multiple files using flask-migrate

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm new in flask. I'm using flask-sqlalchemy ORM, and want to migrate my models from another folder and multiple files using flask-migrate, but not able to migrate. This is my project structure.

**Project Structure**

```
Flask Project
├── config.py
├── migrations
├── API
│   ├── models
       ├── model1.py
       ├── model2.py
       ├── model3.py
├── resources
└── app.py
```

##### app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ="My_Database_Url"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

##### model1.py

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                           server_default=func.now())
    bio = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Student {self.firstname}>'
```

###### In CMD : running this command

```
flask db migrate
```

###### output

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.
```

Comment: You are not importing your models anywhere in your app.py. If you don't import your models, then SQLAlchemy and Alembic will not know they exist.

Answer (score 0):

first of all sorry for my readaction im not a English Native

ok, following your folders first of all, in the root where you have the `app.py` file make a file called `database.py` the name doesn't matter but keep it in mind to do a correct import. In that file you gonna write the following:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

and you have to erase in your `app.py` file the line:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

then, in the same file (app.py) after the app variables write:

```
app = Flask( __name__ )
```

put
`db.init_app(app)` remember to import the file with the database configuration in `app.py` (in this example i called `database.py`)

*app.py file*

```
from database import db

#and to use your models in a route

from API.model1 import Student
from API.model2 import NecesaryClass
```

Finaly, you're set to run in the terminal the database commands (in the root file, where you have the app.py file)

> flask db init

> flask db migrate

> flask db upgrade